# removes part of string in r

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I'm trying to extract **ES** at the end of a string

```
> data <- c("phrases", "phases", "princesses","class","pass")
> data1 <- gsub("(\\w+)(s)+?es\\b", "\\1\\2", data, perl=TRUE)
> gsub("(\\w+)s\\b", "\\1", data1, perl=TRUE)
[1] "phra"    "pha"     "princes" "clas"    "pas"
```

I get this result

```
 [1] "phra"    "pha"     "princes" "clas"    "pas"
```

but in reality what I need to obtain is:

```
[1] "phras"    "phas"     "princess" "clas"    "pas"
```

Comment: if you want to extract only `es`, why does `princesses` become `princes`?

Comment: because at the moment of executing the code only once, it is deleted at the end of the word SES, so what I'm looking for is that the S be respected before ES and only be eliminated.

Comment: what about the code generating `data1`? Isn't that exactly the result you are looking for ?

Comment: My problem is that in the sequence of instructions that I am giving in the first one, it is indicated to eliminate ES, example: in BASES the result is BAS, but in the second instruction the indication is to eliminate the letter S, so instead of BAS the result is BA. What I am really looking for is that the words that were already affected by the first instruction are not affected

Answer (score 2):

You can use a word boundary (`\\b`) if it is guaranteed that each word is followed by a punctuation or is at the end of the string:

```
data <- c("phrases, phases, princesses, bases")

gsub('es\\b', '', data)
# [1] "phras, phas, princess, bas"
```

With your method, just wrap everything till the second `+` with one set of parentheses:

```
gsub("(\\w+s+)es\\b", "\\1", data)
# [1] "phras, phas, princess, bas"
```

There is also no need to make `+` lazy with `?`, since you are trying to match as many consecutive `s`'s as possible.

**Edit:**

OP changed the data and the desired output. Below is a simple solution that removes either `es` or `s` at the end of each string:

```
data <- c("phrases", "phases", "princesses","class","pass")

gsub('(es|s)\\b', '', data)
# [1] "phras"    "phas"     "princess" "clas"     "pas"
```

Comment: My problem is that in the sequence of instructions that I am giving in the first one, it is indicated to eliminate ES, example: in BASES the result is BAS, but in the second instruction the indication is to eliminate the letter S, so instead of BAS the result is BA. What I am really looking for is that the words that were already affected by the first instruction are not affected

Comment: @MaxTC Can you provide an example where this is relevant and that my solution doesn't solve it? Are you trying to remove s at the end only if es wasn't first removed?

Comment: edit my main question, what I want to do is eliminate ES at the end of each word then delete S at the end of each word without affecting the words that were previously affected.

Comment: @MaxTC Edited my answer. Is this what you're looking for? The regex evaluates the `es` before `s`, so `es` is always removed before `s` if it exists at the end of a string.

Comment: Has worked with this: `gsub("ES$|S$)", "", data`, but when you find a prayer you only make the change in the last word you find:  `data2<- c("BASES HABLES", "CLASES","INHOUSE ENVASES","CUMBRES", "CASAS")

    
    data2<- gsub("BLES\\>","BLE",data2)
    data2<- gsub("BRES\\>","BRE", data2)
    
    data2<- gsub("\\b(?!ENVASES\\b)(?!CLASES\\b)(\\w+)?=ES$|S$", "\\2", data2, perl = TRUE)
    
    "BASES HABLE"    "CLASE"          "INHOUSE ENVASE" "CUMBRE"         "CASA"`
 the correct result would be: `"BAS HABLE"    "CLASES"          "INHOUSE ENVASES" "CUMBRE"         "CASA"`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for a lookbehind assertion (which is a 0 length match)

```
"(?<=s)es\\b"
```

or because lookbehind can't have a variable length perl `\K` construct to keep out of match left of `\K`

```
"\\ws\\Kes\\b"
```